# TFT LCD installation failed

Tags: recovery

Connected a 3.5in TFT LCD and ran the LCD35-show script which ran for a bit then rebooted and crashed.
I would just like to get back to the HDMI, but system crashes.
Noobs V2.3 is available but there is no way to launch terminal window.
Not sure what drivers were wiped.
Stops at not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(179,2)